# SQL Server how can I get the code of a foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I can get the code of a stored procedure using the syscomments table.

```
select so.name, sc.text as storedproccode
from sysobjects so (nolock)
inner join syscomments sc (nolock) on sc.id = so.id
where so.name = 'tablename'
```

How can I get the code for a specific foreign key constraint? I have the foreign key name.

Let me clarify what I'm looking for.

I find my table in the Object Explorer and expand the list of keys. If there is a primary key I can then right click on the primary key constraint and bring up the script in a new window.

The code looks like this:

```
USE [Gemini]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [PK_CM_FULFILLMENT_HISTORY]    Script Date: 02/17/2012 16:50:23 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CM_FULFILLMENT_HISTORY] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_CM_FULFILLMENT_HISTORY] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [pan] ASC,
    [RequestCode] ASC,
    [RequestDate] ASC
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [GEMINI_12_Indx_FG]
```

I can also do this with foreign key constraints.

Is there any way to retrive the code (script) of these constraints?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's stored as a string, the values are stored in system tables.  There's a lot less flexibility in constraints so they can be normalized.

Comment: Please see this question - my answer deals with learning about several different kinds of dependencies, including foreign keys. As others mentioned though, SQL Server doesn't store the `ALTER TABLE` script anywhere. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557038/find-tables-that-a-particular-table-depends-on-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a script that does the trick.

```
Declare        @dbname varchar(128)
            ,  @tablename varchar(128)
            ,  @query nvarchar(4000)


select   @dbname = 'gemini'
       , @tablename = 'cm_fulfillment_house'


SET @QUERY = 
'USE ' + @DBNAME + '


SELECT CAST(F.NAME AS VARCHAR(255)) AS ForeignKeyName,
CAST(c.name as varchar(255)) AS ForeignTable,
CAST(fc.name as varchar(255)) AS ForeignColumn,
cast(fc2.name as varchar(255)) as ForeignColumn2,
CAST(p.name as varchar(255)) AS PrimaryTable,
CAST(rc.name as varchar(255)) AS PrimaryColumn,
cast(rc2.name as varchar(255)) as PrimaryColumn2
INTO #GetFKConstraints 
FROM SYSOBJECTS F 
INNER JOIN SYSOBJECTS C ON F.PARENT_OBJ = C.ID
INNER JOIN SYSREFERENCES R on F.ID = R.CONSTID 
INNER JOIN SYSOBJECTS P ON R.RKEYID = P.ID
INNER JOIN SYSCOLUMNS RC ON R.RKEYID = RC.ID AND R.RKEY1 = RC.COLID
INNER JOIN SYSCOLUMNS FC ON R.FKEYID = FC.ID AND R.FKEY1 = FC.COLID
left join syscolumns rc2 on r.rkeyid = rc2.id and r.rkey2 = rc.colid
left join syscolumns fc2 on r.fkeyid = fc2.id and r.fkey2 = fc.colid
WHERE F.TYPE = '+'''F'''+''

select @query = @query + ' and c.name = ''' + @tablename + ''''

+ '

--SELECT * from #GetFKConstraints'+'

SELECT ' + '''ALTER TABLE ''' + '+ ForeignTable + ' + ''' 
DROP CONSTRAINT ''' + '+ ForeignKeyName 
FROM #GetFKConstraints 
ORDER BY ForeignTable'
+'

SELECT ' + '''ALTER TABLE ''' + '+ ForeignTable +' + ''' 
ADD CONSTRAINT ''' + '+ ForeignKeyName +' 
+ ''' FOREIGN KEY ('''+ ' + ForeignColumn + '+ ''') 
REFERENCES ''' + '+ PrimaryTable + ' + '''(''' + '+ PrimaryColumn + '+ ''')''' +
'FROM #GetFKConstraints 
ORDER BY ForeignTable
'
select @query

EXEC (@QUERY)
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the code for a specific foreign key constraint?

You can not be cause it does not exist. Forein key constraings are configured and then the management information is kept in tables, but there is no "code" that is run.

If you look at the INFORMATION_SCHEMA you will find you can find out what constraints exist and what they refer to. But there is no "code". When yo ucreate a foreign key constraing, configuration entries are made in a table of contraints describing the constraint. A FK constriaint is not a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `sys.foreign_keys` and `sys.foreign_key_columns`.  The former will tell you what foreign keys are in a column and the latter will tell you which columns are in which foreign keys.